# Is it possible to round a float on display using CSS or AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have an angularjs properties that contain a float that I display like this :

```
{{fraisDeDep.kilometre}}
```

The display is : 45,4564
How to display 45,45 without have a function that destroy the binding ?

Does the method working for {{fraisDeDep.kilometre * fraisDeDep.indemniteKilometre *fraisDeDep.allerretour}} ?

Comment: http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.filter:number

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the built-in [number filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:number) for this:

```
<div>{{fraisDeDep.kilometre | number:2}}</div>
```

The default `fractionSize` is `2`, so you can also leave it off in this case:

```
<div>{{fraisDeDep.kilometre | number}}</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to format as a float when it's binded to an input element?